# What are Queue classes, Worker Classes, Job Classes in Python rq package

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, queue, python-rq

While reading through the [`rq` docs](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/), I notice that there are some arguments that you can pass to `rq worker` when starting the worker

Example:

```
rq worker --worker-class 'foo.bar.MyWorker'
```

Argument list includes

- `--worker-class` or `-w`: RQ Worker class to use (e.g rq worker --worker-class 'foo.bar.MyWorker')
- `--job-class` or `-j`: RQ Job class to use.
- `--queue-class`: RQ Queue class to use.

What are worker classes, job classes and queue classes, and when do you utilize them?

Answer (score 2):

It's just inheritance of classes ( Worker from rq for example )

Let it as base_worker.py

```
import pseudo_realy_necessery_library_for_every_job

from rq import Worker as BaseClass
class Worker(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, queues=None, *args, **kwargs):
        u'''
        Constructor.

        Accepts the same arguments as the constructor of
        ``rq.worker.Worker``.
        '''


        super().__init__(queues, *args, **kwargs)
```

and u can run

```
rq worker --worker-class='base_worker.Worker'
```

In my case I have exclude reloading library for every new job